# Can I have a customised average network speed in Conky?

Tags: networking

On a fairly tight data limit, I'd like to be able to get a clearer idea what any given stream is costing me in terms of data allowance.

I use conky `{downspeedf}` but this jumps around a lot when a stream is not  absolutely regular.

So I was wondering how, perhaps with vnstat?, I could show a download speed numeric averaged out over a customisable number of seconds, perhaps ten?

Comment: I bet your cost is based on throughput, not speed. You probably need to measure the data used.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm watching a game that I know is 90 minutes long and I know I'm using say 100KiB/s I can do a quick calculation in my head. But it would probably make sense to output in xB/min, although still average out from a sample over say 10 seconds.

Comment: That will give you a poor estimation. Simply measure the number of byte through you router.

Comment: I think that's kind of the same thing. Because {downspeed} in Conky has a rapid response rate, it's too sensitive to give a clear idea of what 90 minutes of that stream is going to be at a glance, throughput-wise. If it were damped out, or averaged over a period of say 10 seconds, it would be more useful.

Comment: The problem is that you speed will actually vary over a long period. It actually varies from second to second. You have not control over what happens on the public Internet, and there will be congestion at various points that will affect you. What you really want is something like NetFlow or IPFIX.

Comment: vnStat supports measuring the average for the last x seconds. With `vnstat -tr 10` you'll get the information for the last 10 seconds. If you'd want it in a more parseable format then recent versions support also `vnstat --json -tr 10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following achieved my aims precisely, thanks to [Teemu Toivola](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10601087/teemu-toivola):

```
${execi 20 vnstat -tr 10 -i wlo1 | grep "rx" | awk '{print $2" "$3}'}
```